# Suma need __init__?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the script below, I would like to give, for example, the number 2. I have of course moved to the if where the message will show me. Then he added to the sum 2. Then I give again, for example, 3, etc. The sum will reach 8 and get the message END.

I do not know if `int (a)` is necessary.

```
from sys import exit

class Glowna_klasa(object):

    def start(self):
        suma = 0
        a = int(input("Take a number: "))
        print("Now suma have: ", suma)

        if int(suma) == 8:
            print("END")
            exit(1)

        if int(a) == 2:
            print("2 sztuki mają: 1.40")

            # here need add to suma ?
            return self.start()

        elif int(a) == 3:
            print("3 sztuki mają: 2.30")
            return self.start()
        elif int(a) == 4:
            print("4 sztuki mają: 3.20")
            return self.start()
        else:
            print("Error, need number")


crv = Glowna_klasa()
crv.start()
```

This is what i need:

```
>>>Take a number: 
2
>>>2 sztuki mają: 1.40
>>>Now suma have: 2
>>>Take a number: 
2
>>>2 sztuki mają: 1.40
>>>Now suma have: 4
>>>Take a number:
4
>>>4 sztuki mają: 3.20
>>>Now suma have: 8
>>>END
```

Comment: If you're asking "do I need to implement `__init__` for my class?": no, `__init__` is not mandatory and there's no reason to add it if your code already does what you want.

Comment: *"I do not know if int (a) is necessary."* No, you don't, because it's already `int`.

Comment: You also don't need a class.

Comment: Hmm but when i try this:

        `if int(a) == 2:
            print("2 sztuki mają: 1.40")
            suma += 2
            return self.start(),suma`

suma still have 0... always.

'suma' must be global variable  ?

Comment: Well what is the first line after `def start(self):`? (hint: it is `suma = 0`)

Comment: Why are you using a class?  This seems to complicate your program with no advantage.

Comment: Why are you using recursion?  The task you describe fits a simple `while` loop quite nicely.  There are many other Stack Overflow questions and many tutorials that will show you how to repeat something until you get to a given value.

Comment: You have right. Now the class is removed

Answer (score 0):

Your overall structure is more complicated than the problem suggests.  You are trying to keep a "running sum" of input, until you reach a given value.  Consider this structure:

```
laczny = 0
while laczny < 8:
    wybor = int(input("Take a number: "))
    laczny += wybor
    print("Now laczny have: ", laczny)
    # work on wybory 0, 1, 2, 3, ...

print("END")
```

No class, no recursion, no exit from the middle.
Easier for you, I hope.

Comment: It's still not what I was thinking ;)

Comment: Now I am confused: when I make this modification to your code, it produces the output you gave in your "answer".

Comment: The result must be added up

Comment: ... "added up" is included in my answer; I had a variable wrong in the `print` statement.